# NSManagedObjectContext property on NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass and wish to fetch one of its child objects given a certain value which is a property of the child "position".

I have written a function `- (ChildObject*)childWithPosition:(int)position`.

Inside here I check if that child exists and return it if it does.

If it doesn't exist then I want to create it.

So...

Can I do this inside the ParentObject...

```
- (ChildObject*)childWithPosition:(int)position
{
    //check if child exists and return it if it does.
    // if it does not exist then...

    ChildObject *child = [[ChildObject alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ChildObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    child.position = position;

    return child;
}
```

My question is, is it OK and safe to use the property self.manageObjectContext on the parent and use this context to insert a new child object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But why don't use `managedObjectContext` property of `NSManagedObject`?

From Apple docs:

> managedObjectContext Returns the managed object context with which the
>   receiver is registered.

So, for example:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* currentContext = parent.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: In this case, parent and child will share the same context. The one of the parent.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but I prefer the initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext method for initing ManagedObjects.

Comment: @Fogmeister Sorry. It was a typo in the code. I fixed it. The insert method is an utility method that I usually create to insert objects within a context.

Comment: That's what I am doing :D the code I put is in the parent object so self.managedObjectContext is the same :D

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes. But using my answer prevent to pass the context around. ;) Each object has a reference to its context.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is. it even must be for the parent to have a relationship with its child :)

===
only objects in the same MOC can be related IIRC